# What's the difference between `export var a = 1` and `export a` in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6 **module**

you can export something from one module in this way:

```
export var a = 1
export function hello(word) { console.log(a + word) }
```

but this way will be wrong:

```
var a = 1
export a
```

Could you tell me the difference and reason ?

Comment: no difference. Like var a = 1. or var a; a = 1; whats the difference?

Comment: *but this way will be wrong* Why do you think that?

Comment: Questions about language design decisions are usually not a good fit for Stack Overflow, since most people here don't work on the language specification. The correct syntax is `export {a}`. Maybe this was done to emphasize that the binding `a` is exported, not just its value. Note that you can export multiple bindings in a single statement: `export {a, b c}`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference. Instead of this:

```
var a = 1;
export a;
```

You should do this:

```
var a = 1;
export { a };
```

Nothing should go wrong. It would be *exactly* the same as:

```
export var a = 1;
```

As for the reason, it was to make it possible to export multiple variables.

Comment: There is a difference. One of them works, the other is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the brackets. I'll fix that.